# Dirac particle in potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, dirac-equation

I want to consider the Dirac equation in one spatial dimension $$ H_D = c\alpha_ip^i +\beta mc^2+\mathbb I_4 V(x),$$

where the potential is given by $$ V(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}0 & |x|>a/2 \\-V_0&|x|\le a/2\end{array}\right.\qquad V_0>0.$$

Now I would like to find the solutions to this equation assuming outgoing (relative to the potential well) solutions with real or imaginary momentum outside the well and a superposition of right- and left propagating solutions inside. Since I'm not quite yet with spinors and solving the Dirac equation, I require some help because I really would like to see how it works. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution online which shows explicitly how to solve the Dirac equation for this potential. Maybe somebody can show me how this is normally done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this paper can help you solve the problem:

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0908/0908.2205.pdf